# How do we actually feel special theory of relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

If I consider a thought experiment for understanding special theory of relativity, In which a person is travelling in a space ship at very very high speed with respect to an observer standing outside the space ship and they both have mechanical clock and both are measuring speed of light but instruments to measure speed of light are set inside space ship only, Let an emitter is set in space ship at point A and a photo receiver is set at point B such that A and B are aligned with direction of motion of space ship. Person inside space ship started emitter and noted time of receive by receiver and calculated speed of light as distance AB was known and at the same time person outside calculated the speed of light by looking at Same emitter and receiver while inside person was calculating. Now I have doubt that will the light hit receiver at the same instant for both the observers? If No then why not? Why person standing outside do not feel that time has slowed down? Will time shown by two mechanical stopwatches same as clock outside will also get slow and as it will tick slower than clock inside ultimately both will reach same position as outside one has more time also? What does slowing down of time actually mean in this case? And what actually the time is?

Comment: I am a high school student in 12th grade and not actually had studied relativity in detail ( all mathematics behind). But now I first want to get strong intuition about this and then want to proceed to real mathematical portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some comments which might help.

If you are on a spaceship moving at 99% the speed of light, your wristwatch will run slow *but so will your brain*, so to you in the spaceship, time seems to run normally.

But now if you leave your wristwatch in the spaceship and take up a position *outside the spaceship, standing still* and the spaceship zooms by you at 99% the speed of light with your wristwatch visible through a window, you will notice its hands moving very slowly. From *this* frame of reference, the clock in the speeding spaceship appears to be running slow.

Special relativity gives you the precise equations you need to figure out the "true" passage of time experienced by moving and nonmoving clocks.

Comment: if with respect to frame of spaceship time got slower as compared to frame of observer outside the spaceship relative to which velocity of spaceship is considered then if they both are observing the event happening in the frame of observer inside then its maybe like recording slow-motion video of that event from frame of spaceship and if we compare that video (like outside observer is seeing) to actual video then there is lag in things happening which really physically has no sense that at the same instant past and future physically and simultaneously exist. If no, then how time got slow

Answer (score 1):

The question is somewhat unclear, and deviates from relativity in a few instances. The situation you describe involves two events, with light-like separation: Emission ($E$) of a light pulse, and reception ($R$).

There is no natural rest-frame for the events. You might think it's the space-ship because the physical devices that transmit (at $A$) and receive ( at $B$) are at rest in that frame, but that is entirely irrelevant. Note: $A\ne E$ and $B \ne R$. The LHS's are points in space in an inertial frame, or straight world-lines in spacetime. The RHS's are events, points in spacetime, that are on those lines.

Your problem has two inertial frames. An 'at rest' frame, $S$, outside the spaceship, and a spaceship, $S'$. We'll put all the origins at $E$.

With that, there is not much to say about the 2 events in the 2 frames. In $S'$:

$$ E = (0,0)'$$
$$ R = (L/c,L)'$$

where coordinates are $(t, x)'$ and $L = x'_B-x'_A$.

What is immediately apparent is that the velocity of propagation is:

$$ v = \frac{x'_R-x'_E}{t'_R-t'_E} = \frac L{L/c}=c$$

As expected.

What relativity tells us is that the interval between two events:

$$ \Delta s^2 = c^2\Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2$$

is invariant. All inertial observers agree on it.

In $S'$, the interval between $E$ and $R$ is:

$$ \Delta s^2 = c^2\big(\frac L c\big)^2 - L^2=0 $$

In $S$, the unprimed at-rest frame in which the rocket is moving at $v$:

$$ E = \big(\gamma(t'_E+\frac{vx'_E}{c^2}),\gamma(x'_E+vt'_E)
\big) = (0,0)$$

$$ R = \big(\gamma(L/c + \frac{vL}{c^2}), \gamma(L+\frac{vL}c\big)$$

With the Bondi k-factor:

$$k = \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac v c}}{\sqrt{1-\frac v c}}$$

we rewrite that as:

$$ E=(0,0)$$
$$ R = (kL/c, kL) $$

It's easy to verify that the speed of propagation is $c$, and the invariant interval is $0$.

Note that $k$ can be any positive real number (that is greater than one or less than one), showing that the rocket frame is not preferred.

At this point the question falls apart. (In the future, label your sub-questions. It makes it easier for ppl to follow. I'll go through them in order starting from $R$):

What does "The same instant" with respect to $R$ mean? Each frame assigns a $t$-coordinate to it, that's it.

The person in $S$ doesn't feel time slow down because he doesn't live in $S'$.

The time on the clock in $S'$ will show $L/c$, while the time in $S$ will show $kL/c$, where $k$ is any number on $[0,\infty)$. It could be more, or it could be less.

Time slowing down doesn't mean anything in this case because your thought problem involved a light-like interval between 2 events.

Obviously, I am not answering "what does time mean?". One takeaway from SR is that: Clocks in $S$ ($S'$) run slow when observed from $S'$ ($S$). A lot of beginners make a fuss over the clock mechanism. No one cares. Mechanical, biological, atomic, pulsars. "Clocks run slow" means "time runs slow". Time is what it is.